# Expectation of a bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Can someone point out where I made a mistake?

Let $X$ be a r.v. such that $P(b<X<c)=1$ for some numbers $b<c$, Show that $b<EX<c$.
My solution is $$EX = \int_{\Omega}XdP=\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{1}_{(b,c)}(\omega)\cdot X(\omega)dP>b\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{1}_{(b,c)}(\omega)dP=b$$ And we can use the same way to prove $EX<c$. $\mathbf{1}_{(b,c)}(\omega)$ is indicator function.

My lecturer said my proof of $EX>b$ is wrong, and he just wrote 'what if $b>\mathbf{1}$' and told me to think about this. I really have no idea about what he pointed out. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Sounds strange to look at $b>1$!

Comment: @Math-fun Yeah，either $b>1$ or $b>$indicator is strange.

Comment: The problem is not wheter $b>1$. But your indicator function $1_{(b,c)}(\omega)$ doesn't necessarily make sense unless your sample space is $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. The proper indicator function would be $1_{\{X \in (b,c)\}}(\omega)$.